# Add numbers from EditTexts

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I've created an Activity where I've got an "Add subject" button. When I press it, it creates an item in a ListView, which is formed by an EditText where the user enters a number.

What I want to do is to add the numbers inside the EditTexts of each item created, depending if the user has created 3, 4, 5, etc. items in the ListView, via button.

Here is the code of the Activity:

```
public class PersActivity extends Activity {

Button start, calcaverage1;

private SubjectAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subject_list_view);

    setupListViewAdapter();

    setupAddMarkButton();

    // Accept button
            Button acceptbn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.start1);
            acceptbn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {   public void onClick(View v) 
                {   
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PersActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);      
                        finish();
                }
            });
}

public void removeClick(View v) {
    Mark itemToRemove = (Mark)v.getTag();
    adapter.remove(itemToRemove);
}

private void setupListViewAdapter() {
    adapter = new SubjectAdapter(PersActivity.this, R.layout.subject_list_item, new ArrayList<Mark>());
    ListView atomPaysListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.subject_list_item);
    atomPaysListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setupAddMarkButton() {
    findViewById(R.id.addsubject).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.insert(new Mark("", 0), 0);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the code of the adapter:

```
public class SubjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Mark> {

protected static final String LOG_TAG = SubjectAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private List<Mark> items;
private int layoutResourceId;
private Context context;

public SubjectAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Mark> items) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MarkHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    holder = new MarkHolder();
    holder.Mark = items.get(position);
    holder.removePaymentButton = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.remove);
    holder.removePaymentButton.setTag(holder.Mark);

    holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.subjectname);
    setNameTextChangeListener(holder);
    holder.value = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.subjectmark);
    setValueTextListeners(holder);

    row.setTag(holder);

    setupItem(holder);
    return row;
}

private void setupItem(MarkHolder holder) {
    holder.name.setText(holder.Mark.getName());
    holder.value.setText(String.valueOf(holder.Mark.getValue()));
}

public static class MarkHolder {
    Mark Mark;
    TextView name;
    TextView value;
    ImageButton removePaymentButton;
}

private void setNameTextChangeListener(final MarkHolder holder) {
    holder.name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            holder.Mark.setName(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    });
}

private void setValueTextListeners(final MarkHolder holder) {
    holder.value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try{
                holder.Mark.setValue(Double.parseDouble(s.toString()));
            }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "error reading double value: " + s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    });
}
}
```

I've implemented serializable to pass data through the adapter:

```
public class Mark implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5435670920302756945L;

private String name = "";
private double value = 0;

public Mark(String name, double value) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setValue(value);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(double value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

Hope there's a solution. Thanks!

Comment: not able to follow, what exactly do you want??

Comment: Add the editText item to the arrayList and call
notifyDatasetChanged
(I dont understand what is the need of serializable and all)

Comment: @AkhilJain I want to add the numbers entered in the EditTexts, depending on if there are 2, 3, 4, etc. EditTexts created in the ListView (each EditText is created when the user presses a button)

Comment: @GeorgeThomas I think I have to iterate over each adapter’s list item and sum up each one’s value, but no idea how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would do it

```
addNumberFromText()
{
    int total=0;
    for(int i=0;i<listView.getChildCount();i++)
    {
        View wantedView = listView.getChildAt(i);
        EditText edtText=view.findViewById(R.id.specificEditTextId);
        //not checking wheter integer valid or not, Please do so
        int value=Integer.parseInt(edtText.toString());
        total+=value;
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"total sum is "+total);
}
```

update your activity from following code

```
public class PersActivity extends Activity 
{

Button start, calcaverage1;

private SubjectAdapter adapter;
ListView atomPaysListView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subject_list_view);
     atomPaysListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.subject_list_item);
    setupListViewAdapter();

    setupAddMarkButton();

    // Accept button
            Button acceptbn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.start1);
            acceptbn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {   public void onClick(View v) 
                {   
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PersActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);      
                        finish();
                }
            });
}

public void removeClick(View v) {
    Mark itemToRemove = (Mark)v.getTag();
    adapter.remove(itemToRemove);
}

private void setupListViewAdapter() {
    adapter = new SubjectAdapter(PersActivity.this, R.layout.subject_list_item, new ArrayList<Mark>());

    atomPaysListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setupAddMarkButton() {
    findViewById(R.id.addsubject).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.insert(new Mark("", 0), 0);
        }
    });
}



addNumberFromText()
    {
        double total=0;
        for(int i=0;i<atomPaysListView.getChildCount();i++)
        {
            View wantedView = atomPaysListView.getChildAt(i);

            /*
            // if edit text
            EditText edt=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            //not checking wheter valid or not, Please do so
            double value=Double.parseDouble(edt.toString());
            */

            //you say edittext, but its a textview or so it seems
            TextView txv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.subjectmark);
            //not checking wheter valid or not, Please do so
            double value=Double.parseDouble(txv.toString());


            total+=value;
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"total sum is "+total);
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work... It gives me a error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getChildCount() from the type ViewGroup

Comment: where did you actually write the above code, `adapter` or `anonymous inner class`???

Comment: Inside the main activity

Comment: I can't run the app. The errors are red exclamation marks

Comment: in which file `MainActivity` or `adapter`?? cause non static reference could possibly be due to ViewHolder and reference Ui components

Comment: Inside PersActivity, which is the main activity of the app

Comment: 1.) please take screenshot and share it which line show error, did you make `addNumberFromText()` method static??

Comment: 1. you are new to android programming, that is very obvious. just tell one thing, the id of the view which you trying to add, `textview` or `edittext` or whatever

Comment: Yes, I'm new to android programming. The id of the TextView is subjectmark

Comment: see now, i would highly recommend to use chat discussion for further queries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59721/discussion-between-isaias-and-akhil-jain).